# PyQt4: QSpinBox doesn't accept values higher than 100

Tags: pyqt4

I am quite new to python and qt, i want to use a spinner that ranges from 0 - 1000000 but the QSpinBox wont go above 100 even when i set the max to be 1000000, i am sure it is really simple to do, bu i have been searching for ages and cannot find anything. here is the code i have used so far:

```
steps_spin = qt.QSpinBox()
steps_spin.setValue(10000)
steps_spin.setMinimum(100)
steps_spin.setSingleStep(100)
```

I hope you guys can help me!

Answer (score 18):

- The default maximum for QSpinBox is 99, so setValue is limited to 99.
- To setValue for something higher than 99 you must call setMaximum/setRange first:

  ```
  steps_spin = QtGui.QSpinBox()
  steps_spin.setMinimum(100)
  steps_spin.setMaximum(100000)
  # alternatively, you may call: steps_spin.setRange(100, 100000)
  steps_spin.setValue(10000)
  ```

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
steps_spin.setRange(0,1000000)
```

Comment: Can you tell why the Qt Designer is not allowing to set the max range to 2,176,999,999

Answer (score 3):

From the [PyQt4 documentation](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qspinbox.html):

> QSpinBox.__ init__ (self, QWidget parent = None)
>
> The parent argument, if not None, causes self to be owned by Qt
>   instead of PyQt.
>
> Constructs a spin box with 0 as minimum value and 99 as maximum value,
>   a step value of 1. The value is initially set to 0. It is parented to
>   parent.
>
> See also setMinimum(), setMaximum(), and setSingleStep().

You can find a similar text in the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qspinbox.html#QSpinBox) of Nokia.

Working code sample:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
steps_spin = QtGui.QSpinBox()
steps_spin.setMaximum(1000000)
steps_spin.setValue(10000)
steps_spin.setMinimum(100)
steps_spin.setSingleStep(100)
steps_spin.show()
```